# Problems setting up Helm-Projectile for emacs

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-helm

I'm new to emacs, about a week and a half now. I'm on a *mac, high sierra, 10.13.2*.

I'm using `use-package`.

I've been trying to set up `helm-projectile`, using a basic config such as [this link](http://nadeemkhedr.com/emacs-tips-and-best-plugins-to-use-with-evil-mode/#helmprojectilelinkhttpsgithubcombbatsovhelmprojectile), but I can't get `helm-projectile-find-file` to work (I'm a previous-vim user and wanted a ctrl-p like setup).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIddj.png) is a screenshot of the error I'm getting when running `helm-projectile-find-file`

To be clear:

- `projectile-find-file` works fine
- `helm-projectile-find-file-in-known-projects` works fine
- `helm-projectile-switch-project` works fine
- etc.

**It's just  `helm-projectile-find-file` that doesn't work.** I'm so stumped as to why and I've been trying to solve this all weekend and so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the relevant settings I'm using in my *.emacs* config file

```
;; Projectile
(use-package projectile
:ensure t
:defer t
:config
(projectile-global-mode))


;; Helm
(use-package helm
:ensure t
:config
(helm-mode 1)
(setq helm-autoresize-mode t)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") #'helm-find-files)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") #'helm-M-x)
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action) ; rebind tab to do persistent action
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-i") 'helm-execute-persistent-action) ; make TAB works in terminal
(define-key helm-map (kbd "C-z")  'helm-select-action) ; list actions using C-z
)


;; Helm Projectile
(use-package helm-projectile
:bind (("C-S-P" . helm-projectile-switch-project))
       :map evil-normal-state-map
       ("C-p" . helm-projectile-find-file))
:ensure t
)
```

[**Here**](https://gist.github.com/nbw/ab0fae7173666c6b411373a9d9ab2aff) is a link for my full *.emacs* config file.

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message **as text** (it's in the `*Messages*` buffer) or better yet `M-x debug-on-error` and copy/paste the full `*Backtrace*` buffer after reproducing.

Comment: FWIW the highlight of the error is `(void-function string-empty-p)`

Comment: Vaguely similar, try adding `(require 'subr-x)` before attempting to invoke the function? https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide/issues/55

Comment: @tripleee worked! than you. I'm not sure how I would have figured that out though..

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit - your question should remain strictly a question. Post that as an answer instead, and accept it when enough time has passed. Maybe also report a bug about the missing dependency.

Answer (score 1):

adding `(require 'subr-x)` to my *.emacs* file worked